# Edit XML and save without changing the tag order

Tags: java, xml

I made this code:

```java
for (final File file : MINE.listFiles()) {
    final Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory
        .newInstance()
        .newDocumentBuilder()
        .parse(new InputSource(file.getAbsolutePath()));

    for (Node node = doc.getFirstChild().getFirstChild(); node != null; node = node.getNextSibling()) {
        if ("skill".equalsIgnoreCase(node.getNodeName())) {
            if (LIST.contains(Integer.parseInt(node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("id").getNodeValue()))) {
                for (Node sub_node = node.getFirstChild(); sub_node != null; sub_node = sub_node.getNextSibling()) {
                    if ("set".equalsIgnoreCase(sub_node.getNodeName())) {
                        final NamedNodeMap Attr = sub_node.getAttributes();

                        if (Attr.getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue().equalsIgnoreCase("targetType")) {
                            Attr.getNamedItem("val").setNodeValue("ENEMY_ONLY");
                            System.out.println("Edit skill: " + node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    final Transformer xformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    xformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(file));
}
```

But the problem is that it change my XML's tag order. I searched different ways but I cannot figure out how to do it. Is there any other way to avoid format the XML and keep order as it is?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Please elaborate on what you mean by that the XML tag order is changed. Include the XML content before and after you executed your method and show where something has been changed which shouldn't be changed.

Comment: @Progman No. His question is ok. We only need to be sure of the XML library he is using. It often comes that a XML API reorder tags without our will.

Comment: I use the default java DOMSource no custom libraries. And my code works fine but it re-order my tags such as <id ="1" name="test"> to <name="test" id="1"> and i don't want this.

Comment: Why is is a problem when the order of *attributes in a tag*  changes? What are you trying to achieve? If this is for diffing purposes, you may want to look at e.g., xmldiff.

Comment: @fewkfwkfewfw These are called "attributes", not "tags". Their order usually doesn't matter. Why is it important for you that they attributes have some specific order?